# Break line on txt file is not desired

Tags: excel, vba

This part of my code will save an excel file as txt file.

I select the range to be copied (in excel) to a new Workbook. This workbook will be saved as txt file. The range will always be a string with 15 columns and 1, 2 or 3 lines.

After being saved as txt file, this creates an extra break line after the pasted string. But i don't want that...

Can you help, please?

```
Sub Gravar_TXT()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim RangeTXT As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 
Dim wbEmail As Workbook, strGetFilename As String 'abrir ficheiro "encomenda"
strGetFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open Import Workbook")

Dim wsEmail As Worksheet, wsTXT As Worksheet

Set wbEmail = Workbooks.Open(strGetFilename)
Set wsTXT = wbEmail.Sheets("TXT")
'With wbEmail 'useless in your code context
   wsTXT.Activate

   xTitleId = "Selecionar Range para incluir no ficheiro TXT"
   Set RangeTXT = Application.Selection
   Set RangeTXT = Application.InputBox("Selecionar Range", xTitleId, RangeTXT.Address, Type:=8)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     
   Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
   RangeTXT.Copy
   With wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
   End With
    saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    wb.SaveAs FileName:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close
     
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End With 'useless in your code context
End Sub
```

[The "Final TXT file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zOkd.png)
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried after doing your research? Please include that in your question, and explain the problem you had with what you tried.

Comment: Would "this creates an extra break line after the pasted string" mean that the pasted range has such an extra empty line, or most probably, the obtained txt file ends in such a empty line?

Comment: @FaneDuru i've placed an image of the obtained txt file. But yes, the obtained txt file ends in such a empty line and its not my fault :). Hope it helps

Comment: Excel add an extra 'Lf' character to append after it. The created file should be directly open and remave the last character. Now I am driving. If nobody will show you how to do it, I will post some code when I will be home.

Comment: @FaneDuru that would be great. I see the point of your idea But I don't know how to do it. I'll wait for you. Thank you a lot

Comment: Back home, now... Your picture does not clarify anything, I am afraid, but it must be an empty row below the existing one, I suppose. I will make a function to be called inside of your code. It will clean the string termination. I will make some tests. It may be `Lf`, like I initially supposed or `CrLf`, which means two elements to be trimmed. I will post an answer in two, three minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Use the next `Sub`, please:

```
Sub cleanTxtFile(fullFilename As String)
  Dim objFSO As Object, objTF As Object, strTXT As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fullFilename, 1)
        strTXT = objTF.ReadAll
    objTF.Close
    
    'Clear the last two strTXT characters (CrLf):
    strTXT = left(strTXT, Len(strTXT) - 2) 'clear the last character
    
    'put back the arranged text:
    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = objFSO.CreateTextFile(fullFilename, True, True)
        Fileout.Write strTXT
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```

It will be called from inside your existing procedure:

```
'existing code...
 'wb.SaveAs FileName:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
  wb.Close

 'Here will be placed above Sub call:
  cleanTxtFile saveFile

 'your existing code...
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 '...
```

I edited your question code and arranged a little from indentation point of view. I observed that the `With wbEmail ... End With` is useless in your code context and I commented these two lines.

Please try it and let me know if it works as you need, or further clarifications are necessary.

Comment: @FaneDuru...Thank you. I will test it and give you Feedback asap.

Comment: @Pedro Ramos: "some issue" does not say too much... Do you receive an error? If yes, what error, on which line? If not, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru...There's some issue with the code.

I've pasted like this:

```
'Here will be placed above Sub
    Call cleanTxtFile 'saveFile
     
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With


End Sub

Sub cleanTxtFile(saveFile As String)
  Dim objFSO As Object, objTF As Object, strTXT As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(saveFile, 1) 'After this step, it will return to the "main sub"
        strTXT = objTF.ReadAll 
    objTF.Close
    
    'Clear the last two strTXT characters (CrLf):
    strTXT = Left(strTXT, Len(strTXT) - 2) 'clear the last character
    
    'put back the arranged text:
    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = objFSO.CreateTextFile(fullFilename, True, True)
        Fileout.Write strTXT
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Anyhow, I recommended to call it like `cleanTxtFile saveFile`. You used `Call cleanTxtFile 'saveFile` which is wrong. Firstly, using Call, you must put the argument between parenthesizes and secondly, you comment the variable name `' saveFile` is not used as parameter...